# Oracle: unimplemented error due to execute immediate command

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have given a task to create a procedure for copying data from the table and insert the copied data inside the same table and the change one of the column data. For example I have a table with with columns(ID, C1,C2....C20), the datas in column "ID" have same value and I want to change to another value after I copied it.
 I tried to use cursor and record since it returns a lot of data and the following is my procedure code:

```
  create or replace procedure copy_data(tab_name varchar2 ,column_to_change  varchar2, change_value varchar2, rowcount number)
is
  stmt varchar2(100);
  stmt2 varchar2(100);
  type test_cursor is REF CURSOR ;
  cur_cv test_cursor;
  v_test_rec job%rowtype;
begin
  stmt := 'v_test_rec.'||column_to_change;
  stmt2 := 'insert into ' || tab_name || ' values v_test_rec ';
  open cur_cv for 'select * from ' || tab_name;
  loop
  fetch cur_cv into v_test_rec;
  stmt := change_value;    
  execute immediate (stmt2);
  exit when cur_cv%rowcount > (rowcount - 1); 
  end loop;
  close cur_cv;
end;
/
```

tab_name is the table to copy data from, column_to_change is the column that I want to change the data inside, change_value is the value I want to change to from column_to_change,  rowcount is the total count of the column.

when I compiled it, it was success, but when I execute it :

```
execute copy_data ('job', 'ccn_cd', 'ITUE02', 112);
```

I got error, and the error is following:

```
ORA-03001: 
ORA-06512: "HR.COPY_DATA", 行16
ORA-06512: 行1
03001. 00000 -  "unimplemented feature"
*Cause:    This feature is not implemented.
*Action:   None.
```

I am trying to understand which part of my code was wrong but still can't figure it out. I am sorry that my english isn't that good. Can anyone give me some hints or solutions to my problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Check this: http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/137567/ - it could be your issue too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it must something like this one.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ... AS

SUBTYPE test_rec_type IS job%rowtype;
PROCEDURE copy_data(tab_name varchar2 ,column_to_change  varchar2, change_value varchar2, rowcount number);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ... AS

PROCEDURE copy_data(tab_name varchar2 ,column_to_change  varchar2, change_value varchar2, rowcount number) is

  stmt varchar2(100);
  stmt2 varchar2(100);
  cur_cv SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_test_rec test_rec_type;

begin
      stmt2 := 'insert into ' || tab_name || ' values :v_test_rec ';
      open cur_cv for 'select * from ' || tab_name;
      loop
         fetch cur_cv into v_test_rec;
         execute immediate stmt2 USING v_test_rec;
         ...
      end LOOP; 

END copy_data;
```

However, you can use PL/SQL types only in latest Oracle 12.1 release. Older releases do not support them.

Check also documentation for [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01115): *If the data type is a collection or record type, then it must be declared in a package specification.*

Comment: Hi Wernfried,
Thanks dfor your reply. I have tried your way by changing my code but I got an error like this:
pls-00457 

since i am using japanese version of dql developer, in translation i think it will be "statement must be is sql form".

Comment: Overall code :
 create or replace procedure copy_data(tab_name varchar2 ,column_to_change  varchar2, change_value varchar2, rowcount number)
is
  stmt varchar2(100);
  stmt2 varchar2(100);
  type test_cursor is REF CURSOR ;
  cur_cv test_cursor;
  v_test_rec job%rowtype;
begin
  stmt2 := 'insert into ' || tab_name || ' values :v_test_rec ';
  open cur_cv for 'select * from ' || tab_name;
  loop
  fetch cur_cv into v_test_rec;
  execute immediate stmt2 USING v_test_rec;
  exit when cur_cv%rowcount > (rowcount - 1); 
  end loop;
  close cur_cv;
end;
/

Comment: @nicklowkc: v_test_rec is a record. Expressions in USING must be SQL data types. A record is a non-SQL type.

Comment: @Nitish, I checked the documentation. In Oracle 11.2 the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#sthref632) says: *No bind variable has a data type that SQL does not support (such as BOOLEAN in Example 7-2).* but in 12c it is possible. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried. I havent learned that much about package yet but I will try to place it inside a package. About the procedure, I tried to use sql statement and declare it statement, and use execute immediate in begin block. I will try your code next.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit:
I've tried your answer, but it doesn't work.
1. There is a "END LOOP" missing to get it compiled
2. I get ORA-00902: invalid datatype at line of "execute immediate".

I've created a small testcase just for your example, but can't get it working due to ora-00902.

Comment: @D.Lohrsträter please see my correction

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: Sorry, still doesn't work. I've created a full testcase below:
`create table mytab (id number, status varchar2(2));

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ETST AS

SUBTYPE test_rec_type IS MYTAB%rowtype;
PROCEDURE copy_data(tab_name varchar2);
END;
/
`
-- Part2 in next comment:

Comment: Part 2:
`CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ETST AS
PROCEDURE copy_data(tab_name varchar2) is
stmt2 varchar2(100);
cur_cv SYS_REFCURSOR;
v_test_rec test_rec_type;

begin
stmt2 := 'insert into ' || tab_name || ' values :v_test_rec ';
open cur_cv for 'select * from '||tab_name;
loop
fetch cur_cv into v_test_rec;
execute immediate stmt2 USING v_test_rec;
end loop;
end copy_data;
END;
/
execute ETST.copy_data('MYTAB');
`

Comment: @D.Lohrsträter please open a new question for it.